# jQuery check checkbox ajax POST output variable to php isset

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I check if a checkbox is checked and if it is output back to php before form is submitted. I know the checkbox status can be checked using jQuery and is(':checked') and possibly an ajax POST back.

I have searched and not found what I am looking for.

confirmation.php

```
    <script>
      $(function() {
        if ($('#noemail').attr('checked')) {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               data: "noemail=1",
               url: "confirmation.php",
               success: function(msg) {
                   alert("wowwww... checked");
               }
           });
        }
});
</script> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="noemail" id="noemail" checked="checked" type="checkbox">

<?php
   if((isset($_GET['noemail'])&&($_GET['noemail'] == '1')){
       session_register('noemail');
   }
?>
```

I need to output back to confirmation.php the following which is a function in the php to register.

```
session_register('noemail');
```

instead of the alert message would I need an ajax url POST to set a variable that can be checked in the php using isset and if it is use that to activate the function.

Comment: If you want to check if it is checked before the form is submitted, why not just check it using Javascript? If that's not what you mean, please edit your question since it is a bit unclear at the moment.

Comment: or using jQuery you can use: is(':checked') Take a look here for reference: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @Sigma - Isn't jQuery Javascript? ;-)

Comment: @Magnus you are correct... also am i :)

Comment: @Sigma Maybe the "_or_ using jQuery" could be "_and_ using jQuery". :-)

Comment: Sure, in jquery you can use `.is(':checked')` ... but theres still a lot of other code needed to do... but the question is pretty unclear the details. So thats just one piece of the puzzle. (given the question has the jquery tag, I assume jquery-esque answers are wanted).

Comment: I would suggest using `prop('checked')` if you already have a variable containing a jQuery object.  `:checked` is useful for if you are doing a selector, however if you already have the elements, simply checking the property is less work than making jQuery evaluate a pseudo selector.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether a checkbox is checked with JavaScript:

HTML File:

```
<input name="noemail" id="noemail" type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">
<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>
```

JavaSccript:

```
 function myFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("text");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: _"Try this"_ isn't a proper description. A good answer should include a full explanation of what the code does, what issue it solves and how it solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Sincerly ok sometimes things are complicated sometimes not but jQuery is to write less code... as the slogan says: write less, do more... anyway here is an example and i hope helps @wolfen to understand and to solve as well what exactly he/she needs.

```js
$(function() {
 if ($('#noemail').attr('checked')) {
    alert("wowwww... checked");
          // do what you want or need
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="noemail" id="noemail" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
```